# finitely satisfiability of delta in the proof of compactness theorem

Tags: compactness, model-theory

I am reading proof of compactness theorem for sentential logic in Enderton's book, *A mathematical introduction to logic*.

> (*Compactness theorem*) A set of wffs is satisfiable iff every finite subset is satisfiable.

He wrote a strategy before the proof:

> 1. we take our given finitely satisfiable set $\Sigma$ and extend it to a maximal such set $\Delta$,
> 2. we utilize $\Delta$ to make a truth assignment that satisfies $\Delta$.

I am struggling to prove that the set $\Delta$ is finitely satisfiable. In this vein, the textbook says:

> Furthermore, (3) $\Delta$ is finitely satisfiable. For any finite subset is already a finite subset of some $\Delta$n and hence is satisfiable.

And why did we pick maximal $\Delta$ ? would it be valid in the sense that if some wff Ω has the same two properties that ∆ has and ∆ ⊆ Ω, then Ω = ∆?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am struggling to prove that the set $\Delta$ is finitely satisfiable.

You haven't explained the construction of $\Delta$, but I'm assuming $\Delta = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\Delta_n$ for some increasing chain of sets of formulas $\Delta_n$, each of which is finitely satisfiable.

What Enderton wrote is a fine explanation, but I'll fill in the details for you. Let $\delta = \{\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_k\}$ be a finite subset of $\Delta$. Then for each $1\leq i \leq k$, since $\varphi_i\in \Delta$, $\varphi_i\in \Delta_{n_i}$ for some $n_i\in \mathbb{N}$. Let $N = \max(n_1,\dots,n_k)$. Then $\varphi_i\in \Delta_{n_i}\subseteq \Delta_N$ for all $1\leq i \leq k$, so $\delta\subseteq \Delta_N$. Now since $\Delta_N$ is finitely satisfiable, $\delta$ is satisfiable.

> And why did we pick maximal $\Delta$?

Maximality of $\Delta$ is used in making the truth assignment that satisfies $\Delta$. You should read the proof carefully to see why we need $\Delta$ to be maximal. But the basic idea is this: we want $\Delta$ to decide the truth value of all atomic formulas, so that we don't have to make any "guesses" when we specify the truth assignment.

> would it be valid in the sense that if some wff $\Omega$ has the same two properties that $\Delta$ has and $\Delta\subseteq \Omega$, then $\Omega = \Delta$?

I'm not sure what you're asking. This is the definition of maximality...